# ClassNotFoundException with XposedBridge

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception

I'm writing an Xposed module (which runs), and I just added an activity to it, so I could tweak some settings in the application.

I created an Activity the regular Android way, and added it to my manifest (the package name is correct). I also added the class name to my xposed_init file.

I still get this in my logcat:

```
07-02 15:50:33.275: E/AndroidRuntime(2505): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "tweaks.vinit.xdictionary.DictSettings" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/bin/XposedBridge.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

What could the problem be?

Edit: here's a more detailed log.

```
07-02 18:33:25.485: W/Xposed(16780): Package name for /data/app/com.zst.xposed.xuimod-1.apk had to be retrieved via parser
07-02 18:33:25.489: W/ActivityThread(16780): Application tweaks.vinit.xdictionary can be debugged on port 8100...
07-02 18:33:25.491: D/AndroidRuntime(16780): Shutting down VM
07-02 18:33:25.491: W/dalvikvm(16780): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41632d40)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780): Process: tweaks.vinit.xdictionary, PID: 16780
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{tweaks.vinit.xdictionary/tweaks.vinit.xdictionary.TempClass}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "tweaks.vinit.xdictionary.TempClass" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/bin/XposedBridge.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "tweaks.vinit.xdictionary.TempClass" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/bin/XposedBridge.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1084)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2126)
07-02 18:33:25.493: E/AndroidRuntime(16780):    ... 12 more
```

Edit 2: also, TempClas (second log) is the same as DictSettings (first log), just a different name. Here's the code:

```
package tweaks.vinit.xdictionary;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TempClass extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.templayout);
    }

}
```

Edit 3: aaand, here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tweaks.vinit.xdictionary"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.9.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hasCode="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="tweaks.vinit.xdictionary.TempClass"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="xposedmodule"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="xposeddescription"
            android:value="App that searches for the definition of your selection on dictionary.com" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="xposedminversion"
            android:value="30" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: See my updated answer! (Made it a community wiki by accident)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `DictSettings` uses any Xposed-specific stuff, using it in your `Activity` won't work, as the Xposed classes are only available in the module part of your APK, not the 'normal app' part!

If you look closely in your `logcat`, you may notice `dalvikvm` complaining about a missing base class of `DictSettings`, which then causes the `ClassNotFoundException`!

Edit: why are you using `hasCode=false`? Try changing it to `true`!

Comment: But DictSettings isn't using any Xposed stuff :/ not that I know of, anyway.

Comment: Can you post a more detailed `logcat`?

Comment: Also, your Activity doesn't need to be in xposed_init!

Comment: I've edited my post. The xposed_init thing was a last ditch attempt at getting it to work, it wasn't in there initially.

Comment: What about `TempClass`? Does that contain *any* Xposed related code?

Comment: Oh, sorry. `TempClass` is essentially the same as `DictSettings`, I just repeated the whole procedure. I've edited my post with the code, there's barely anything.

Comment: How are you launching this activity? From the launcher, or from within a method hook? If the latter is thr case, that won't work either as the classes of your module are not magically available in the hooks!

Comment: Yes, I thought as much, but I'm doing it from the launcher :/ wait, I'll add my manifest as well. Oh, I should also point out that I've tried just using `.TempClass` within the manifest, instead of the whole package name. That didn't work either.